# Forcing JSON JAXB to ignore 'type' properties for polymorphic types with Jersey

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs, jackson

I am using an abstract class to localize my models to different languages. This is the inheritance chain that I have set up:

```java
//Base model, contains localized fields
public class Restaurant extends LocalizedModel<LocalizedRestaurantData>{

...

}

//Abstract class to support localized fields for all my models
@XmlRootElement
public abstract class LocalizedModel<T extends LocalizedData> {

    private T en;

    public T getEn() {
        return en;
    }
    public void setEn(T en) {
        this.en = en;
    }
    ...
}

//Implementation of the localized fields for the restaurant class.
@XmlRootElement
public class LocalizedRestaurantData extends LocalizedData{

    protected String name;
    protected String address;
    ...
}
```

This all works fine in my Jersey JSON web service, except for one thing: All the instances of the localized property `en` contain an extra field `type`:

`Restaurant` JSON:

```
{
"en": {
        "type": "localizedRestaurantData",
        "address": "1234 Main St.",
        "name": "Tacos Folie"
    },
 ...
}
```

This `type` field is undesired and undesirable especially since it seems to be also required by Jackson when parsing an object. I've added `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"type"})` in my code without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple attempts and soliciting help on both the Jackson and the Jersey mailing list, the solution I found is:

My JERSEY context was implementing `ContextResolver<JSONJAXBContext>`. That needs to be changed to `ContextResolver<JacksonJsonProvider>` to use the pure JSON parser.

Secondly, the JacksonJsonProvider needs to configured as follows:

```
JacksonJsonProvider jjp = new JacksonJsonProvider();
jjp.configure(Feature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
jjp.configure(Feature.WRITE_NULL_PROPERTIES, false);
```

And used as the context.

Finally, the following method needs to be overriden as follows in the ContextResolver:

```
@Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
      Set<Object> s = new HashSet<Object>();
      JacksonJsonProvider jjp = new JacksonJsonProvider();
      jjp.configure(Feature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
      jjp.configure(Feature.WRITE_NULL_PROPERTIES, false);
      s.add(jjp);
      return s;
    }
```